# Why spring boot generates jar or war file with .original extension?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar, war

Why after building spring boot app, it generates two jar or war files with `.original` extension? I use spring boot maven build plugin.
For example:

1. `application.jar`
2. `application.jar.original`

Comment: How are you building your war? Are you using Maven? Can you share your pom.xml? Are you using spring-boot-maven-plugin?

Comment: I use spring boot maven build plugin..

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The answer is that you are using `repackage` goal in your `spring-boot-maven-plugin`.
So, What it does?

Maven first builds your project and packages your classes and resources into a WAR `(${artifactId}.war)` file.

Then, repackaging happens. In this goal, all the dependencies mentioned in the pom.xml are packaged inside a new WAR `(${artifactId}.war)` and the previously generated war is renamed to `${artifactId}.war.original`.

Comment: Nice Answer. In case of need to skip the repackage goal: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60398974/2183717. Works with spring boot 2.7.12

Answer (score 8):

I assume that you're using the spring boot maven build plugin.  This behavior is documented [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html): https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html